# Cambiar campo para filtrar en buscador Angular 12

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filtro, angular-material

Estoy haciendo un buscador dentro de una tabla, no se como cambiar por que campo va a filtrar por defecto lo esta haciendo con mi penultimo campo y me gustaria cambiarlo adjunto mi codigo:

TS:

```
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label>Buscador</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Nombre" input>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Si esta filtrando solo por un campo especial debes tener en tu `ngOnInit(){     this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function (record:tu objeto,filter:string) {....}`para tener el comportamiento que decís el cual no es el por default que posee la tabla

Answer (score 0):

```
filterPredicate: (data: T, filter: string) => boolean
```

> FilterPredicate comprueba si un objeto de datos coincide con la cadena
> de filtro de la fuente de datos. De forma predeterminada, cada objeto
> de datos se convierte en una cadena de sus propiedades y devuelve
> verdadero si el filtro tiene al menos una aparición en esa cadena.

la cual retorna un booleano de acuerdo a la coincidencia o no de la búsqueda
por lo cual basta con quitarlo para que vuelva a tener el comportamiento por default
asi podriás filtrar por cualquier campo
Si quieres filtar por cualquier campo  aplicando un filtro selectivo en el codigo remplaza nombre por el nombre del campo así se especifica en cual propiedad de tus datos hay que aplicar el filtro :
usar filterPredicate la  cual retorna un booleano de acuerdo a la coincidencia o no de la búsqueda del campo

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<...>(.....)
    this.filtroTabla();
  }
    filtroTabla(){
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: Tipo, filter: string) => {
        return data.nombre.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter);
   }

    applyFilter(event: Event): void {
    const filter = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

teoria en 1.[filter](https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/mat-table-filter/)------2.[mas sobre filter](https://careydevelopment.us/blog/how-to-filter-on-specific-columns-with-filterpredicate-in-an-angular-material-table)---

En este tutorial podes ver que el comportamiento default es por cualquier campo si no se usa filterPredicate
3.[filter default](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/angularya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=48&codigo=48&inicio=40)